# Given just the sum and difference of two vectors, how can I find two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

If $v + w =(5,1)$ and $v − w =(1,5)$
 **compute** and draw $v$ and $w$.

Comment: Add and subtract the two equations.

Comment: This is a linear equation system with two variables and two equations.

Comment: If $x+y=a$ and $x-y=b,$ then $x=\frac{a+b}2$ and $y=\frac{a-b}2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the two equations will yield you a fast result for $v$ :

$$2v=(5,1)+(1,5)\Leftrightarrow2v =(6,6) \Leftrightarrow v = (3,3)$$

Same as subtracting the two equations, will yield you a fast result for $w$ :

$$2w = (5,1)-(1,5) \Leftrightarrow2w = (4,-4) \Leftrightarrow w=(2,-2)$$

It's always good to look for such fast ways, cause it really makes your solution shorter.

If you're looking for a more general way, give variable coordinates to your vectors and solve the $2 \times 2$ system derived :

$$v = (v_1,v_2)$$

$$w= (w_1,w_2)$$

So you would get the system :

$$\begin{cases} (v_1,v_2) + (w_1,w_2) = (5,1) \\ (v_1,v_2) - (w_1,w_2) = (1,5)\end{cases}$$

which you can solve and find the same results as above.

I'll leave the drawing part to you.